# Does {name} always equal {username} in Forgotten Password template?

Tags: templates, system-messages, forgot-password, messages, username

Does the name variable in the forgot password email template always equal the username?

[image: forgot password template]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, {name} variable in the forgot password email template always equals the username.

To be sure, you can see it within the file `system/expressionengine/modules/member/mod.member_auth.php` around line number 732 - 740 (EE v2.6.1).