# Forgot Password Email Notification not rendering {username}

Tags: cartthrob, profile-edit

I am using Profile:Edit to display the "Forgot Password"/Reset form. They work fine. I get the Notification email, but in the email I get this:

===========

Admin,

To reset your password, please go to the following page:

http://local.729beauty.com:8888/?ACT=78&resetcode=s4ss0gFz&return=profile%2Freset_password

Then log in with your username: {username}

If you do not wish to reset your password, ignore this message. It will 
expire in 24 hours.

729 Beauty 
http://local.729beauty.com:8888/

============

Notice that {username} does not get rendered.

I found this post: [Does {name} always equal {username} in Forgotten Password template?](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/12772/does-name-always-equal-username-in-forgotten-password-template) which suggests that {name} and {username} are the same, but not so. In my case, {name} = Admin, and {username} = super_admin.

I am not sure if this is an issue with EE install or Profile:Edit. Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

I would say this is an EE omission or simply a typo, although I've not used Profile:Edit before.

The text in your email notification *(Design > Message Pages > Email Notifications)* is the default 'forgot password' notification, and when you look at this page in EE, you can see the variables available for use in the template; `{username}` is not an option but its been included in the template.

[image: Forgot password notification template]

Although `{name}` and `{username}` can be different, EE doesn't offer the facility to remind people of their username at this point, only to reset password. Other templates do include the `{username}` variable, so I can't imagine it would be too difficult to add.

It would make a nice touch to be able to include it in the password reset process, as this is triggered by your email address, which might not be the username.